# Javascript child objects

Tags: javascript, oop

My javascript app is getting big and I want to split it over multiple files. Currently I have it wrapped like

```
var myApp = function() { /*functions and variables here*/ }
```

And I want something like this, with each child object in different file:

```
var myApp = new function() { }

myApp.childObject1 = new function() {

    this.func= function() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

myApp.childObject2 = new function() {

    this.func= function() {
        console.log('world');
    }
}

myApp.childObject1.func();
myApp.childObject2.func();
```

It works, but I'm wondering if it is the correct way to do it.

Thank you for your answers. I found this article http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html most helpful.

Comment: You should ask this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Victory codereview could also be a good place for this question, but there's no reason such a question can't be asked here....However, as benjarwar pointed out, it's a duplicate question, so it should be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine. Just find a good pattern and go with it.

http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/

One of the first links I found searching for JavaScript module patterns

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can split your namespace implementation among multiple code files. Of course, you should consider internal (or external) dependencies and also if it is actually necessary!

There are a bunch of articles on how to do namespacing in JS.

For example:

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/

Give it a shot.